# Why is it that when using select2 in laravel, the data is displayed in duplicate?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, laravel-10

I want to display the location name based on the province. I have successfully displayed and retrieved the province data but when I want to display the location data, the data appears double even though it is not double in the database. what is the solution to this problem? here is the ui of the dropdown
[dropdown ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzmn4.png)

and here is the code I created in view.blade:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            [tag:[tag:$("#selectProv").select2({
                placeholder:"Pilih Provinsi",
                ajax: {
                    url: "{{ route('advance.provinsi') }}",
                    processResults: function({data}){
                        console.log(data);
                        return {
                            results: $.map(data, function(item){
                                return {
                                    id: item.id,
                                    text: item.provinsi
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#selectProv").change(function() {
                let id = $('#selectProv').val();
                
                $("#selectLoc").select2({
                    placeholder:"Pilih Lokasi",
                    ajax: {
                        url: "{{ url('/selectLoc') }}/" + id,
                        processResults: function({data}){
                            console.log(data);
                            return {
                                results: $.map(data, function(item){
                                    // console.log(item);
                                    return {
                                        id: item.id,
                                        text: item.lokasi
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                
            });  

});
```

and here is the code I created in the controller:

```
class locationController extends Controller
{
    public function provinsi() {
        $prov = Provinsi::where('provinsi', 'LIKE', '%'.request('q').'%') -> orderBy('provinsi','asc') -> paginate(50);

        return response() -> json($prov);
    }

    public function lokasi($id) {
        $lokasi = Lokasi::where('provinsi_id', $id) -> where('lokasi', 'LIKE', '%'.request('q').'%') -> orderBy('lokasi','asc') -> paginate(50);

        return response() -> json($lokasi);
    }
}
```

I want when I want to select a location (dropdown at the bottom of the attached image) based on the province name, there are no duplicates.

Comment: Are they duplicated already when you receive them as a response to your request?

Comment: No, I don't want to duplicate. but the results that appear are always duplicated.

Comment: I understand that 1. you don't want duplicates and 2. the location values are always duplicated. From this situation, we need to identify where and why they are duplicated. I wonder whether it is the fault of your client-side or your server-side. This is why I asked you whether the response your browser gets on province change already has duplicates, or the client-side duplicates some distinct values. I understand your problem and merely ask for further details so we narrow-down the problem-space for clarity.

Comment: Also, you have shared a `provinsi` and a `lokasi` actions with us, but your client-side seems to trigger `url('/selectLoc')`, so I wonder what that url turns out to be and whether it really triggers the exact action you shared with us.